# Performance and life-cycle of a HttpClient request to the localhost

Tags: java, http, network-programming, solrj

We have a service, called Solr, that offers http-api. There's a Java client that consumes it. At the moment, they (service and the client) are not big enough so that we can deploy both of them on the same machine to avoid any network latency. We still wanna use http-api to consume the service so that the future decoupling will be seamless.

I'm not a computer-networks guy but tried to figure out the life-cycle of a http-request. But that applies to a true web http request. It'd be great if you could validate below.

- Request starts at app layer and gets wrapped a couple of times until it reaches the physical layer
- Contact DNS for the IP address
- Send the request to the destination IP over TCP.
- Follow shortest/smartest path to the destination.
- Destination listens on the port number and forwards the incoming to the right application.
- Application returns the response and then it is sent back to the source in a similar fashion.

Question

1. If the request is sent to the url "localhost:8983", how does it compare to the actual web-request in terms of performance. Which one of the above steps are eliminated by default.

   If it matters, please note that I'm using Apache HttpClient (4.3) to talk to the Solr service hosted on the same machine.
2. Does it matter if they are part of the same JVM?

   Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)  Nothing changes.  All requests will follow the same path that you outlined in your question.  The only difference is that there will only be one hop from the client to the server (localhost).

2.)  No, it does not matter.  There still has to be a http request.  That http request will not care if the message is going to the same jvm or not.  It will still follow the steps you outlined in your question.

The requests to the solr jvm via http on the same machine should be very fast and I wouldn't worry about it too much.  However, you should try to make sure you configure your http client correctly by using a threaded connection manager vs the default single threaded manager.  You also might need to determine the size of your connection pool based on your load, but the requests should be pretty quick.